# Inverted question mark only on Microsoft Office applications

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-office

My dad has a notebook and the key which has the "/?°" symbols acts like ctrl. Known factory problem. Anyway, his keyboard also has a "?" marked under the "w" key.

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> will display the "?" character (question, interrogation mark).

Except on Office applications, like Word and Outlook, which will output "¿".

I've searched Word and Outlook menus looking for a parameter that could be, somehow, remapping the notebooks keyboards, applying different regional configurations, language, or encodings. Since it only happens on Office apps, I believe the solution is within its options, but I was unable to find it where.

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> will display ? correctly, but I am stumped by this problem. I could remap the keys and make "/?° behave correctly, but my curiosity now is eating me alive. Why only on Office?

Answer (score 1):

¿

```
&#191;
```

Is the HTML entity for a reversed question mark.

So if you hold ALT and type 191(I'm on a laptop, can't test this), it should output that.

As for Office, must be a setting. Try summoning the "insert" menu in Word, which will show you many symbols. Find the reversed question mark and if there is a custom shortcut present, that will be your answer.

Comment: Alt + 168 will do this. Alt + 191 produces ┐

Comment: @Ciaran: Anything above 127 depends on your system's codepage. (I wish it was easier to type Unicode codepoints like that...)

Comment: Point taken :).

Comment: You can use `Alt+0191` to produce the inverted question mark.  Adding the zero forces Windows to use the UTF page instead of ANSI/Windows-1251.

Answer (score 0):

Word has an annoying Autocorrect feature that replaces characters as you type. Open Tools → Autocorrect Options, look if there is anything that generates a ¿ character, and remove it if so.

If that's not it, you can use this same feature to replace the ¿ character with a ? whenever Word thinks you typed it.

Answer (score 0):

I went to insert/symbol and assigned a shortcut to the normal question mark (?). This seems to have solved this nuisance.